# 'out of gas' error when running a payable function on Remix+TestRPC

Tags: remix, testrpc

I'm using Remix connected to TestRPC and I'm getting an out of gas error when calling the sendEther() function with the argument set to the address of one of the accounts created by TestRPC at startup:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Test
{

    function sendEther(address toAddr) public payable
    {
        toAddr.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

I know that an out of gas error usually means that there was some kind of exception in the function. I tried this in geth + Mist Wallet and it worked fine... Also, running this through Remix debugger did not show me at all what the problem was.

Comment: I've tried with latest version of testrpc: ganache-cli v6.0.3, it appears to be a bug in them. Please report it to their github repo.

Comment: Out of gas used to mean error before Byzantium (block num 4,370,000). Now to detect an error check the `status` field of the tx receipt. `1` is success, and `0` is failure.